# Chromecast webapp custom receiver video source not found

Tags: chromecast

I am working with chromecast and a webapp using the chrome browser. I created a custom reciever and use my video player in the receiver page. Everything works fine, the player is initializing on the choromecast and I can see it on my TV but the most important thing doesn't work is that the video source is not found, I always get a 'NETWORK_NO_SOURCE 3   No HTMLMediaElement src found', even though the source is correct and in the developer console and network tab there are no errors and the video gets a 206 partial download code this is good but still the video element is basically telling that the source is not found which makes no sense.

The video has CORS enabled so CORS is not the issue.

I really don't understand why this is happening.

Any help is greatly appreciated it.

Thank you.